# npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! git dep preparation failed, when installing packages with npm install

Tags: node.js, git, vue.js, npm

When I run `npm install` in a project, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command /usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/home/vivek/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! The git reference could not be found
npm ERR! npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects checkout 4.0
npm ERR! npm ERR! error: pathspec '4.0' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

In the `package.json` file there is no mention of any branch or tag 4.0:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.21",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "web3": "1.0.0-beta.37",
    "websocket": "^1.0.28"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "^1.17.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the package.json file in question.

Comment: Thank you @creme332 for responding, I have added package.json file.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your error with node 18.18.2. By inspecting the debug log, it seems that the problem comes from the `@npmcli` package (`/@npmcli/git/lib/make-error.js`). One of the project dependencies probably depends on it.

Comment: Some of the packages are outdated (as per `npm outdated` ) and even `npm update --save` does not fix the issue.

Comment: You could delete the current `package.json` and manually install each dependency to their latest version in a new `package.json` file. However this will introduce breaking changes in the code.  I don't see any other solutions.

Comment: @creme332 thank you for idea, I tried installing manually but it's the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is most likely caused by outdated/broken packages.

### Check for outdated packages

To check for outdated packages, you can run `npm outdated` to get a list of your outdated packages.

### Update your outdated packages

To fix outdated packages without introducing breaking changes, you can try `npm update --save`.

However, sometimes (like in this case), it is not possible to fix the error without introducing breaking changes.

### Last resort solution

As a last resort,

1. Delete your `package.json` file and `node_modules` folder.
2. Create a new `package.json` file with `npm init -y`.
3. and re-install all your packages manually **without specifying the versions** (to let npm do its work figuring out the right version).

To install dependencies to their latest version, run:

```
npm install web3 vue vue-router vuex websocket
```

To install development dependencies, run (replace `...` with remaining packages):

```bash
npm install -D @vue/cli-plugin-babel @vue/cli-plugin-eslint @vue/cli-service ...
```

You will end up with a new `package.json`  without any errors (except some deprecation warnings outside our reach to fix):

```
{
  "name": "test-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.4.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0",
    "web3": "^4.3.0",
    "websocket": "^1.0.34"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.19.2",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.16"
  }
}
```

Note: You can also replace your old `package.json` with the one above and simply run `npm install`.

At this point, some parts of your code may not work properly so you will have to refer the documentation of each package for instructions on migration.

Comment: @vicky If you feel that my answer has solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick next to the upvote button. This helps keep the focus on other questions which still don't have answers.